# Why sum x y is of type (Num a) => a -> a -> a in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, type-inference, typeclass

I've been reading about Haskell and I'm having a hard time understanding how function definitions are handled in this language.

Let's say I'm defining a `sum` function:

```
let sum x y = x + y
```

if I query Haskell for its type

```
:t sum
```

I get

```
sum :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

1. What does it mean the `=>` operator? Does it have anything to do with lambda expressions? That's how one signals that what is following the `=>` operator is one, in C#.
2. What does the `a -> a -> a` mean? By eye inspection on a number of different functions I've been trying out, it seems the initial `a -> a` are the arguments and the final `-> a` is the result of the sum function. If that is right, why not something as `(a, a) -> a`, which seems way more intuitive?

Comment: If you want to understand Haskell, you better get a (good) introduction instead of asking SO about every part of the language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/how-to-learn-haskell/1016986#1016986 links to a few good resources and has further advice.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**0.** The Haskell `=>` has nothing to do with C#'s `=>`. In Haskell an anonymous function is created with

```
\x -> x * x
```

Also, don't name the function `sum` because [such a function](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Asum) already exists in Prelude. Let's call it `plus` from now on to avoid confusion.

**1.** Anyway, the `=>` in Haskell provides a context to the type. For instance:

```
show :: (Show a) => a -> String
```

Here, The `Show a =>` means `a` type must be an instance of the *type class* `Show`, which means `a` must be convertible to a string. Similarly, `(Num a) => a -> a -> a` means the `a` type must be an instance of the type class Num, which means `a` must be like a number. This puts a constraint on `a` so that `show` or `plus` won't accept some unsupported input, e.g. `plus "56" "abc"`. (String is not like a number.)

A type class is similar to C#'s interface, or more specifically, an [interface base-type constraint in generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230736/can-c-sharp-generics-have-a-specific-base-type). See the question [*Explain Type Classes in Haskell*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685626/explain-type-classes-in-haskell) for more info.

**2.** `a -> a -> a` means `a -> (a -> a)`. Therefore, it is actually a unary function that returns another function.

```
plus x = \y -> x + y
```

This makes partial application (currying) very easy.  Partial application is used a lot esp. when using higher order functions. For instance we could use

```
map (plus 4) [1,2,3,4]
```

to add 4 to every element of the list. In fact we could again use partial application to define:

```
plusFourToList :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
plusFourToList = map (plus 4)
```

If a function is written in the form `(a,b,c,...)->z` by default, we would have to introduce a lot of lambdas:

```
plusFourToList = \l -> map(\y -> plus(4,y), l)
```

Comment: Good answer, except that I always cringe when I hear someone say that type classes are like interface classes.  They have a somewhat analogous role, but reasoning from that analogy will lead you seriously astray.  In particular in Haskell a type class is not itself a type, so you can't write "[Num]" to mean a list of numbers.

Comment: Though writing (Num a) => [a] is not really so different. I believe, so long as you make it clear that the interface analogy is just a simple one to help you get started, it is okay.

Comment: Even if C# had a `Num` interface, something like `List<Num>` is still quite different from `(Num a) => [a]`, because `[5::Int, 3.5::Double]` is not a valid value of type `(Num a) => [a]` in Haskell. I think this surprises a lot of people when they first see type classes.

Answer (score 10):

This is because

**Every function in Haskell takes a *single parameter* and returns a *single value***

If a function need to take multiple value, the function would have been a curried function or it have to take a *single tuple*.

If we add a parentheses, the function signature becomes:

```
sum :: (Num a) => a -> (a -> a)
```

In Haskell, the function signature: `A -> B` means a function the "domain" of the function is `A` and the "Codomain" of the function is `B`; or in a programmer's language, the function takes a parameter of type `A` and returns a value of type `B`.

Therefore, the function definition `sum :: Num -> (Num -> Num)` means sum is "a function that takes a parameter of type `a` and returns a function of type `Num -> Num`".

In effect, this leads to currying/partial function.

The concept of currying is essential in functional languages like Haskell, because you will want to do things like:

```
map (sum 5) [1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 1, 3, 4]  -- note: it is usually better to use (+ 5)
```

In that code, (sum 5) is a function that takes a single parameter, this function (sum 5) will be called for each item in the list, e.g. ((sum 5) 1) returns 6.

If `sum` had a signature of `sum :: (Num, Num) -> Num`, then sum would have to receive both of its parameter at the same time because now sum is a "function that receives a `tuple (Num, Num)` and returns a Num".

Now, the second question, what does `Num a => a -> a` means? It's basically a shorthand for saying that each time you see `a` in the signature, replace it with Num or with one of its derived class.

Comment: You are abusing the notation a bit: `Num` is a typeclass, not a type.

Answer (score 5):

`Num a =>` means "in the following, `a` shall refer to a type which is an instance of the typeclass `Num`" (which is kinda like an interface for number types).

The `=>` operator separates the "typeclass constraints" from the "body" of the type. It's kind of like the `where` operator for generic constraints in C#. You can read it as a logical implication like "if `a` is a numeric type then `sum` can be used with type `a -> a -> a`".

`a -> a -> a` means "a function that takes an `a` and returns a function which takes an `a` and returns an `a`". For this to make sense you need to understand that `sum x y` parses as `(sum x) y`.

In other words: you first call `sum` with the argument `x`. You then get back a new function of type `a -> a`. You then call that function with the argument `y` and now you get back a function of type `a`, where `a` is the type of `x` and `y` and must be an instance of the `Num` typeclass.

If you want `sum` to have type `Num a => (a,a) -> a`, you can define it as `sum (x,y) = x+y`. In this case you have a function which takes a tuple containing two `a`s and returns an `a` (where `a` is again an instance of the `Num` typeclass).

However the "curry style" (functions returning functions to simulate multiple parameters) is much more often used than the tuple style because it allows you to easily partially apply functions. Example `map (sum 5) [1,2,3]`. If you had defined `sum` with a tuple, you'd have to do `map (\y -> sum 5 y) [1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 4):

it is `a -> a -> a` rather than `(a, a) -> a` because of [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Fun fact: Currying was (re)invented by Haskell Curry! Basically it means if you supply one one argument you'll get back another function of type `a -> a`, a partial application of sum.

Comment: Even after reading the intro to the Wikipedia article, I can't get what is the point of currying :(

Comment: I don't get the point either! It's just one of those things you *do* in functional programming...

Comment: You curry functions so you can partially apply them. Want to add 3 to every element in a list? No problem! - map (+3) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: @Paul Harvey: Actually, `map (+3)` is bad example of partial application, it really is an. operator section. `map ((+) 3)` is partial application.

Comment: If you have function "sendMessage to type content" and you often send numberic status messages to "server", you could create helper function with partial application: "sendStatus = sendMessage server number" and use it like "sendStatus 10".

Comment: @Matajon: In Haskell the partial application of an infix operator is called a section, yes. It's still partial application however.

Comment: Another way to think about it: what does 'plus 1' return? A fully-featured function of its own which binds one of the inputs to 1. The ability to trivially generate new functions from existing ones, even whole families of new functions, through elementary operations like partial application, is the point.

Answer (score 4):

The Haskell documentation isn't too clear about it, but (Num a) => means that the function works for all cases where a is a Num or derives from it (therefore is a number).

Also see: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~en1000/haskell/inbuilt.html