# What does `Num a => a` mean in Haskell type system?

Tags: haskell

If I force Haskell to infer the type of a number I'll get `Num a => a`. For example:

```
Prelude> :t 1
1 :: Num a => a
```

But what does `a => a` mean?

Comment: This may answer your question, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742700/5781248

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`1 :: Num a => a` means that `1` has some type `a`, where `a` is an instance of the `Num` typeclass. Note that `Num` is not a type, but a typeclass, which describes common properties of various types. The `Num` typeclass, for example, describes types that are numeric, and so support basic arithmetic. The native machine integer type `Int` is an instance of `Num`, as is the arbitrary-sized `Integer`, the floating point type `Double`, and even the rational number type `Rational`.

Comment: Not some type. Every type.

Comment: @dfeuer Not every type. Any type. Each instance of `1` has one and only one type at runtime. Try to do something like `(,) <$> (+ (1 :: Int)) <*> (+ (1 :: Float)) $ 1` and you won't have a good time.

Comment: @AndrewRay, I suppose it's arguably more like "each type". `1` is operationally a function from a `Num` dictionary to a value. OOP programmers coming to Haskell often assume it's "some", which would allow things like `p :: Num a => a; p = 1 :: Int`.

Answer (score 10):

`a => a` doesn't mean anything. The complete phrase is `Num a => a`. This means "a" is an instance of the `Num` type class.

You  could also read it as `(Num a) => a`. It provides a context to say that `a` is numerical.
However, it is not the *type* of `a`; it just says that `a` should be in the `Num` type *class* .
Type classes are a little like interfaces in object-oriented programming, in that they define certain behaviours, without defining `a` in detail.

Note that there is a difference between `->`  and `=>` . The first is used for the function signature; the second is used to show type classes.

Comment: I didn't get it. The type of `a` is `Num`. But why we need to say `=> a` then?

Comment: For me `Num a => a` is something like this: `a` has type `Num` and it is an `a`. It's a fuzzy.

Comment: `Num a` is telling you something about `a`. `Num` is a type class, not a type. A little like an interface in object-oriented programming, it defines some conditions that `a` should fulfill without defining `a` in detail.

Answer (score 5):

The typing `1 :: Num a => a` means "`1` is of type `a`, for all types `a` in typeclass `Num`". More succintly, it means "`1` is of any numeric type".

Because of this typing, you can pass `1` to any function requiring any numeric type, such as `Int`, `Double`, etc.

Extending your example a bit, we also have `[1,2,3] :: Num a => [a]`. This means "`[1,2,3]` is a list of values of type `a`, for all types `a` in typeclass `Num`". In other words, "`[1,2,3]` is a list of values of any numeric type".

Answer (score 0):

Expression `1::Num a => a` can be broken down in 3 parts for reading/understanding purposes.

Let's build step by step :

`1 ::`  says **1 has the type of**

`c :: Char` says **c has the type of Char**

**Everything before => is a "class constraint"**,so inserting `Num a` between :: and =>

i.e. `1 :: Num a => a` says **"1 has the type of `a`, but not just any type but with a class constraint where `a` is a member of Num class.**