# Understanding (1+)

Tags: haskell

the type of 1+ is given as :

```
Prelude> :t (1+)
(1+) :: Num a => a -> a
```

Is the correct way to read this function as :

1+ takes a Num and returns a function of type `a -> a` ?

Comment: No. The type of `(1+)` is `a -> a`, where there must be an instance for `Num a`. So it can be `Int -> Int` or `Integer -> Integer`, because the instances `Num Int` and `Num Integer` are defined by the Prelude, but `(1+)` can't be `String -> String` unless you define an instance `Num String`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why sum x y is of type (Num a) => a -> a -> a in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742637/why-sum-x-y-is-of-type-num-a-a-a-a-in-haskell)

Comment: Actually you are kinda right... Haskell has type classes (`Num` is one of them). They are implemented using so-called *dictionaries*. Basically functions that have some constraints like `Num a =>` will become functions with *extra dictionary arguments* which are the dictionaries related to the classes in the constraints and they bring around the implementation of the various operations. In this case `(1+)` is equivalent to `\numDict x -> (+) numDict 1 x` (where `+` as you see takes an extra argument too). But forget about this until you have learnt more haskell.

Comment: Exactly. And a `Num`-dictionary is not at all a number, it's more like _the toolkit_ that allows you to use values as numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1+` takes an `a` and returns an `a` with the restriction that `a` must be an instance of `Num`.

Answer (score 4):

No, `Num a` is a *class constraint*, which is implied by the different arrow (`=>`).

`+1` is a function from `a` to `a` where `a` must be an instance of the `Num` typeclass.

For more information see the [part of Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses).

Answer (score 0):

No, in Haskell the part before the => means the class constraint to which a parameter has to be an instance of. So,

```
(1+) :: Num a => a -> a
```

It means (1+) is a function that takes a parameter "a" and returns a parameter "a" where the parameter "a" has to be an instance of the class constraint Num.

Here you can see the entire definition of the Num class constraint: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num